# Subsetting with negative indices: best practices?

Tags: r

Say I have a function for subsetting (this is just a minimal example):

```
f <- function(x, ind = seq(length(x))) {
  x[ind]
}
```

(Note: one could use only `seq(x)` instead of `seq(length(x))`, but I don't find it very clear.)

So, if

```
x <- 1:5
ind <- c(2, 4)
ind2 <- which(x > 5) # integer(0)
```

I have the following results:

```
f(x) 
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
f(x, ind)
[1] 2 4
f(x, -ind)
[1] 1 3 5
f(x, ind2)
integer(0)
f(x, -ind2)
integer(0)
```

For the last result, we would have wanted to get all `x`, but this is a common cause of error (as mentionned in the book *Advanced R*).

So, if I want to make a function for removing indices, I use:

```
f2 <- function(x, ind.rm) {
  f(x, ind = `if`(length(ind.rm) > 0, -ind.rm, seq(length(x))))
}
```

Then I get what I wanted:

```
f2(x, ind)
[1] 1 3 5
f2(x, ind2)
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

**My question is:** 
Can I do something cleaner and that doesn't need passing `seq(length(x))` explicitly in `f2` but using directly the default value of `f`'s parameter `ind` when `ind.rm` is `integer(0)`?

Comment: Best practice would be not to use `\`if\`` like it was a function.

Comment: @HongOoi Yet, it is.

Comment: `ind = if(length(ind.rm) > 0) -ind.rm else seq(length(x))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To implement "parameter1 = if(cond1) then value1 else default_value_of_param1", I used `formals` to get default parameters as a `call`:

```
f <- function(x, ind.row = seq_len(nrow(x)), ind.col = seq_len(ncol(x))) {
  x[ind.row, ind.col]
}

f2 <- function(x, ind.row.rm = integer(0), ind.col.rm = integer(0)) {
  f.args <- formals(f)
  f(x, 
    ind.row = `if`(length(ind.row.rm) > 0, -ind.row.rm, eval(f.args$ind.row)),
    ind.col = `if`(length(ind.col.rm) > 0, -ind.col.rm, eval(f.args$ind.col)))
}
```

Then:

```
> x <- matrix(1:6, 2)

> f2(x, 1:2)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]

> f2(x, , 1:2)
[1] 5 6

> f2(x, 1, 2)
[1] 2 6

> f2(x, , 1)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    5
[2,]    4    6

> f2(x, 1, )
[1] 2 4 6

> f2(x)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    5
[2,]    2    4    6
```

Answer (score 2):

What you have isn't bad, but if you want to avoid passing the default value of a default argument you could restructure like this:

```
f2 <- function(x, ind.rm) {
    `if`(length(ind.rm) > 0, f(x,-ind.rm), f(x))
}
```

which is slightly shorter than what you have.

**On Edit**

Based on the comments, it seems you want to be able to *pass* a function nothing (rather than simply not pass at all), so that it uses the default value. You can do so by writing a function which is set up to receive nothing, also known as `NULL`. You can rewrite your `f` as:

```
f <- function(x, ind = NULL) {
    if(is.null(ind)){ind <- seq(length(x))}
    x[ind]
}
```

`NULL` functions as a flag which tells the receiving function to use a default value for the parameter, although that default value must be set in the body of the function.

Now `f2` can be rewritten as

```
f2 <- function(x, ind.rm) {
    f(x, ind = `if`(length(ind.rm) > 0, -ind.rm, NULL))
}
```

This is slightly more readable than what you have, but at the cost of making the original function slightly longer.

Comment: could you explain the use of if with backticks here?  Is this the same as `ifelse`?  `?ifelse` notes that: Further note that `if(test) yes else no` is much more efficient and often much preferable to `ifelse(test, yes, no)` whenever test is a simple true/false result, i.e., when `length(test) == 1`.

Comment: That is the syntax for R's if *function* (similar to `? :` in C). The back-ticks are to distinguish it from the control-flow use of the keyword `if`). I actually don't use this version, but saw no reason to change OP's usage here. You are correct that it is like `ifelse`.

Comment: R's "ordinary" `if`is itself a function. The backticks evidently denote a non-standard way of invoking this function. I suspect that under the hood `if(test) yes else no` is in some sense syntactic sugar for the back-ticked version.

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 As I used the `if` to get a value and pass this value as a parameter, I prefered using the backticks so that it is written as a function. In John's answer, using if-then-else is fine.

`ifelse` is not really as if-then-else, and I usually try to not use it. Just check the result of `ifelse(0 > 1, NULL, 1:5)` to see what I mean.

Comment: @Coleman
Your answer is good for the problem I presented. I wanted the minimal example to be as simple as possible, I should have been more precise. Actually, I subset on matrix-like objects so that I would have 4 cases (because I have indices for rows and columns), and 8 cases if I want the same behaviour on a third parameter. I would like something that say, `parameter1 = if(cond1) then value1 else default_value_of_param` and the same thing for parameter2 or any other parameters..

Answer (score 2):

If you anticipate having "empty" negative indices a lot, you can get a performance improvement for these cases if you can avoid the indexing used by `x[seq(x)]` as opposed to just `x`.  In other words, if you are able to combine `f` and `f2` into something like:

```
new_f <- function(x, ind.rm){
  if(length(ind.rm)) x[-ind.rm] else x
}
```

There will be a huge speedup in the case of empty negative indices.

```
n <- 1000000L
x <- 1:n
ind <- seq(0L,n,2L)
ind2 <- which(x>n+1) # integer(0)

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  f2(x, ind),
  new_f(x, ind),
  f2(x, ind2),
  new_f(x, ind2)
)
all.equal(f2(x, ind), new_f(x, ind)) # TRUE - same result at about same speed
all.equal(f2(x, ind2), new_f(x, ind2)) # TRUE - same result at much faster speed

Unit: nanoseconds
           expr     min        lq        mean  median       uq      max neval
     f2(x, ind) 6223596 7377396.5 11039152.47 9317005 10271521 50434514   100
  new_f(x, ind) 6190239 7398993.0 11129271.17 9239386 10202882 59717093   100
    f2(x, ind2) 6823589 7992571.5 11267034.52 9217149 10568524 63417978   100
 new_f(x, ind2)     428    1283.5     5414.74    6843     7271    14969   100
```

Comment: This is good to know. I usually care a lot about performance.
In this particular case, this is not something that I will call a lot of times. 
So 11ms is good for me.
As in my comment to John's answer, I need this behaviour on 2 or 3 parameters, so using typical if-then-else statements would produce complex code.